# Clone phone with TWRP (Galaxy S4 mini)

Tags: backup, twrp

I have two identical* phones (Samsung Galaxy S4 mini), both with TWRP installed. I want to clone one to the other so that all applications, data, settings etc are preserved.

How I did my backup:

- First, I backed up all partitions except Cache to my SD card.
- Then, I copied `/data/media/0` to the SD card
- I cloned the SD card to another SD card (both identical hardware) and inserted it into the other phone.

How I tried to restore it:

- Sadly, TWRP didn't show my backup in the restore list
- I then made a backup of the bad phone to generate folder name and replaced its content with the good backup (someone on Reddit suggested that)
- Recovery showed that backup, but the list of partitions was empty
- After this, the folder with the backup was not present on the SD card anymore

Is there a way to make TWRP accept backups from other devices? Are there other ways to create backups but not bound to a single device?

---

*With identical, I mean hardware-wise. They run different software: The one I want to clone runs vanilla Android, but I flashed its recovery with TWRP by booting into Download mode. On the other one, I additionally used TWRP to install LineageOS as I was told [here](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/serranoltexx/install).

Comment: I did something similar long time back on Note 2. I took a complete Nandroid backup of first device and restored it as it on second device  (using the Nandroid saved on ext.SD and transferring that to second device **except** for `EFS` partition (which has device specific info). It worked. Try this **ONLY** if the models of both phones, version of OS, type of OS is identical. If  security updates  is different , don't restore `/system` to be on the safer side

Comment: Software wise, both phones are completely different: the one I want to overwrite has already been flashed with LineageOS and the other is still vanilla Android as when I bought it.

Comment: Then you can't clone in one shot. You will need to backup apps,  using Titanium and restore on other. For call logs and contacts also you can use Titanium. see the tag and wiki. Not recommended at all with Nandroid OR flash stock on the second device to bring it up to same level OR flash Lineage on first if you want to go Nandroid way

Comment: I tried to avoid Titanium because the phone hasn't been rooted yet. I thought I could do an image backup on one containing every information bit by bit and restore it on the other like I'm used to with computers. Why do they need to be the same Android version if the backup is supposed to contain the ROM too? Or have I missed something?

Comment: See my edit for some clarification. When I start Titanium I get the same (but translated) screen as in the beginning of this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uuw1_UW-rlc